# Como faço uma comparação de um caractere no intervalo de um alfabeto?

Tags: java, int, char

A questão é a seguinte:
 1)Ajude    a   universidade a montar as    divisões    do  laboratório de  programação.    Para    isso,   escreva um algoritmo    que leia    o   nome    do  aluno   e   diga    em  qual    divisão ele está respeitando    a   regra   abaixo:
-alunos cujo    nome    começa  comas   letras  de **A**    a   **K**   estão   na  **D1**;
-alunos cujo    nome    começa  com as  letras  de  **L**   a   **N**   estão   na  **D2**;
-alunos cujo    nome    começa  com as  letras  de  **O**   a   **Z**   estão   na  **D3**.
Dica:   use o método    `charAt(posição)`?

```
 public class ex4a3{
    public static void main (String[] args){
       String nome = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite seu nome para
descobrir sua divisao:");
   char letra = nome.charAt(0); 

   if(letra >= "a" && letra <= "l"){
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Voce esta na divisao D1");
   }

   }
}
```

Comment: Seria melhor se você formulasse uma pergunta ou declarasse qual o problema em vez de passar a pergunta como se fosse um exercício, pois assim ajudaria na sua compreensão do exercício, em vez de recebê-lo pronto sem compreender e em vez de aprender necessitar de ajuda toda vez que precisar fazer um exercício.

Answer (score 1):

Essa questão é sobre os tipos que você está usando.

`"a"` (note as aspas duplas, o caracter `"`) é uma `String`.

`'a'` (note o apóstrofo/aspas simples, o caracter `'`) é um `char`.

Note também que `'A'` é diferente de `'a'`. Os caracteres básicos (sem acentos, cedilhas nem outras marcas diferenciais) tem a numeração definida pela tabela [ASCII](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).

---

Outra alternativa é usar expressões regulares. Devido ao como você redigiu a pergunta, parece que você está aprendendo programação em Java, então talvez não se sinta muito a vontade com expressões regulares. Na Wikipédia tem [um exemplo de como escrever expressões regulares](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Express%C3%A3o_regular#Teoria_de_linguagens_formais).

No exemplo abaixo, você pode brincar com os valores da variável `nome` para saber o que combina com um padrão (`Pattern`). No caso, o padrão que eu criei encaixa com qualquer coisa que comece com as letras de `a` a `k`, ignorando se está em caixa alta ou caixa baixa.

```
import totalcross.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Teste {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String nome = "luiz";
        Pattern pattern = new Pattern("^[a-k].*", "i");
        if (pattern.matches(nome)) {
            System.out.println("match");
        } else {
            System.out.println("not match");
        }
    }

}
```